# Building mosync on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mosync

I recently downloaded [mosync](http://www.mosync.com/pages/previous-versions-source-code-and-night-builds) and i am trying to build it on my Ubuntu 12.0.4 dev machine. However, I cannot find any build instructions - and opening the .sln file in MonoDevelop raised several exceptions because of the Windows libraries dependencies.

Has anyone managed to build the mosync app on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the MoSync SDK comprising Eclipse, as far I am aware, there isn't currently (as of May 2013) an *official* means of building the SDK on Linux, regardless of what the (now-outdated) [official MoSync-on-Linux post](http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/building-mosync-source-linux) used to suggest.

I posed a similar question regarding a Linux/Ubuntu build myself, posting as 'sixman9', in the following MoSync forum thread:

[What is missing from a fully functioning Linux version of MoSync dev tools - Please outline the issues?](http://www.mosync.com/content/what-missing-fully-functioning-linux-version-mosync-dev-tools-please-outline-issues)

I got plenty of help regarding building MoSync on Ubuntu, Fredrik Eldh appears to be the Guru regarding the issues surrounding a Linux port (and has submitted code updates), another user, 'sudurais' got the MoSync SDK built for Ubuntu, and shares the steps he took within the thread.

Having coaxed this information out of them, I *was* in the process of writing a definitive bash build script, the start(s) of which are outlined in the forum post. However, I'm currently side-tracked with 'Life' (Baby/House move), so my involvement is on hold, at least for the time-being.

I hope this info helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful link in your answer. I will try to use it to get MoSync built on Ubuntu. Would it be possible to reach out to you if/when I get stuck? - that would be very much appreciated. BTW, yeah, life DOES get in the way ;). Good luck with the baby/house move etc!

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli - Yeh, feel free, I'll try to help as much as I can, given my personal circumstances. As I roughly know what is needed to compile MoSync for Ubuntu, including extracting the required profiles from the Windows EXE using command-line 7Zip (see forum post), I could, if you like, post the beginnings of my definitive build script into a Github project, you could fork it, and we could collaborate on getting it finished, if you like? Let me know what you'd like to do, ok?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to help. I really like the idea of collaborating via a Github project. Please let me know when you have created the Github project, so I can get started. As an aside, this is something I will be doing in my spare time (probably like you), so I am unlikely to bombard/inundate you with urgent questions etc - although I may need a little help in the beginning as I am not that familiar with Github. Look forward to getting started!

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli - OK, create a free account on [Github](http://www.github.com), login in, then fork my [MoSync-on-Ubuntu](https://github.com/sixman9/mosyncUbuntuBuild) project (which creates your own copy), install some form of Git on your machine ('sudo apt-get install git'), clone ***your*** version of my repository (see Git clone URL within your new Github fork, use 'git clone <git-url>'), work as required, contact me via Github messaging, I'll let you know what to do next ;-) Cheers.

Comment: +1 @BigRich: I've forked your project. I will follow the instructions and contact you if (when?!) I come unstuck at some point; I am on a 64bit OS and from one of the comments, there are issues building for the 64bit 12.0.4 OS - so I am bracing myself :).  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if Github does this by default, but go ahead and 'watch' my repository (I'm watching yours), I'll create issues in place of direct messages (I thought Github had messaging, seems not). That way, I can explain what I think we need to do next, I've 'dumped' some build knowledge in a sub-folder within the project, however, it might not be straight-forward to decipher it.

Comment: The build script does not build. It merely echoes to screen, the selected branch choice. Need to find a way to actually clone the selected branch (and necessary dependencies) to build on Ubuntu. I have created a document called Notes, we can hopefully use that to comment - if not, I'll just send you my email so we can communicate directly. tx

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli - check your email ;-)